# JSON object response

Tags: android, json

I am working on an Android app. There is an activity retrieving JSON data from a remote PHP file.

This is the received response:

```
[{"result":{"cel_verificado":"888"}}]
```

And this the function where I need to retrieve the value for cel_certificado:

I am getting following log details:

```
D/MainActivity: ID RESPUESTA CEL en SHOWJSONCELL = [{"result":{"cel_verificado":"888"}}]


 private void showJSONCel(String response){

        Log.d(TAG,"ID RESPUESTA CEL en SHOWJSONCELL = "+response);


        try {

            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("result");
            String recibido = user.getString("cel_verificado");
            cel_verificado_valor= recibido;
            Log.d(TAG, "ESTOY EN MAIN GET DATA SHOWJSONcel TRY"+cel_verificado_valor);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ESTOY EN MAIN GET DATA SHOW JSON CELL error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It throws the exception.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add your exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the response from the server that you posted, you receive a JSONArray, not a JSONObject. So you need to parse it as such and take the first element from it:

```
try {
    JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(response);
    JSONObject jObj = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("result");
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a JSONArray

```
[{"result":{"cel_verificado":"888"}}
```

You have to get the first object JSONObject(0) and then use the string "result" which will again give a JSON object back to you

EDIT: Post the full json Array if this is just a snippet from somewhere between.